# Adding params to render methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I would like to be able to pass "params" to the "is_following" method as follows:

```
       respond_to |format|
          format.json { render json: @user, :methods => [:is_following params] }
       end
```

However, when I put "params" after the method name, it throws an error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ']'
```

.

.

When I render the JSON (without the is_following method), it looks like this:

`[{"id":81,"image_url":"https://graph.facebook.com/123213123/picture?type=large","full_name":"John Johnson"},{"id":85,"image_url":"https://graph.facebook.com/123123123/picture?type=large","full_name":"Bill Nye"}]`

I want to add the is_following method so that the JSON loos like this:

`[{"id":81,"image_url":"https://graph.facebook.com/123213123/picture?type=large","full_name":"John Johnson",'is_following'=>4},{"id":85,"image_url":"https://graph.facebook.com/123123123/picture?type=large","full_name":"Bill Nye",'is_following'=>9}]`

**EDIT**

```
def friends
  @user = User.first
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @user.friends.order("first_name ASC"), :methods => [:is_following], :only => [:id] }
  end
end
```

and is_following method in model is:

```
def is_following params
    return Friendship.where("user_id = ? AND friend_id = ?", params[:user_id], self.id).count
end
```

Anyone know how to solve this? I will give you a million dollars.

Comment: Syntax error tells you about missing the comma after `:is_following`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Brian,

Just change this code:

```
:methods => [:is_following params]
```

to

```
:is_following => is_following(params)
```

EDIT

Here is a better way to do this anyway:

```
def friends
  @users = User.find_by_sql("SELECT users.*, 
      count(distinct friendships.friend_id) as is_following FROM users
      LEFT JOIN friendships ON users.id = friendships.user_id
      WHERE users.id = " + params[:user_id] + "
      GROUP BY users.id
      ORDER BY users.name ASC")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried `def friends
  @user = User.first
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @user.friends.order("first_name ASC"), :methods => :is_following => is_following(params), :only => [:id] }
  end
end`

Comment: I think I'll have to get creative, and come up with a way around it. It just won't work.

Comment: I added an alternative method instead of doing multiple database queries.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS SQL QUERY! *NEVER* use params directly in a query string, it's a massive security hole.